# Play Framework: How to serialize raw fields to JSON with nested elements

Tags: scala, playframework

I need to serialize a `String` and an `Option[Boolean]`:

```
val myWrites = (
  (__ \ "box").write(
    (
      (__ \ "name").write[String] ~
      (__ \ "default").writeNullable[Boolean]
    ).tupled
  )
)
```

If `Option[Boolean]` is `Some` then I'd expect

```
{
  "box": {
     "name": "John",
     "default": true
  }
}
```

... while if `Option[Boolean]` is `None` I'd expect

```
{
  "box": {
     "name": "John"
  }
}
```

Given the following variables...

```
val name = "John"
val default = Some(true)
```

... how do I pass them to the `Writes`? I've tried this:

```
myWrites.writes(name, defaul)
```

... but it doesn't compile:

```
No Json serializer found for type play.api.libs.functional.FunctionalBuilder[play.api.libs.json.OWrites]#CanBuild2[String,Option[Boolean]].
Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
[error] (__ \ "box").write(
```

Comment: Your code works for me. Maybe try `Json.toJson( (name, default) )(myWrites)`. Notice that you should pass `Tuple2` (so parentheses are necessary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its just a typo in your writes. you have defaul vs default

I was able to use

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

val myWrites = (
  (__ \ "box").write(
  (
   (__ \ "name").write[String] ~
     (__ \ "default").writeNullable[Boolean]
   ).tupled
)
 )

myWrites.writes("hi",Some(true))
```

and I got back

```
res0: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"box":{"name":"hi","default":true}}
```